# Extract Last Bracketed Characters from String in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, string, extract

My strings are filenames like this:

Sample Text (A12 V1.1)

Sample (V2) Text (A9 V2.3 8.99)

Sample Very Text (A34 8.3 V4)

How do I extract only the string starting with but excluding the 'V', contained within the last brackets only?

i.e. - 1.1, 2.3, 4

Comment: What have you tried already? This looks like a perfect case to use regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this UDF

```
Function ExtractByRegex(sTxt As String)
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "V\d+(.)?(\d+)?"
    If .Test(sTxt) Then ExtractByRegex = .Execute(sTxt)(0).Value
End With
End Function
```

### Update

Here's another version in which you can format the output

```
Sub Test_ExtractByRegex_UDF()
MsgBox ExtractByRegex("A9 V2.3 8.99")
End Sub

Function ExtractByRegex(sTxt As String)
With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    .Pattern = "V\d+(.)?(\d+)?"
    If .Test(sTxt) Then sTxt = Replace(.Execute(sTxt)(0).Value, "V", "")

    If Not InStr(sTxt, ".") Then sTxt = sTxt & "." & "000"
    ExtractByRegex = Split(sTxt, ".")(0) & IIf(InStr(sTxt, "."), ".", "") & Format(Split(sTxt, ".")(1), "000")
End With
End Function
```

Comment: Very nice YasserKhalil. RegEx appears very powerful indeed. But, now I realize my output should not include the 'V'. How would I eliminate the 'V' from the extraction? I added a right funtion, but I am not sure if this is the correct syntax.


Right(.Execute(vTxt)(0).Value, Len(.Execute(vTxt)(0)) - 1)

Comment: You can use mid or use replace like that `Replace(.Execute(sTxt)(0).Value, "V", "")`

Comment: That works perfectly, YasserKhalil. Thanks! One more thing: is there a way to pad the decimal portion of the number with zeros, so that the result is like - 1.001, 1.020, 2.003, 4.000, etc.? The padding would display much better in a long list of values.

Comment: YasserKhalil, the UDF you provided is returning on filenames like: "IPV32_20.dll" returns "V32-20", and "IMV1.dll" returns "V1.". These filenames do not contain brackets, so they should not be returning. Help?

Answer (score 0):

VBA's string functions can duplicate the results from a static pattern and you might want to return a true number if you are dropping the *V* prefix.

```
Option Explicit

Function ExtractWithoutRegex(sTxt As String)

    Dim b As Long, v As Long

    b = InStrRev(sTxt, "(")
    v = InStr(b, sTxt, "V")

    ExtractWithoutRegex = vbNullString

    If v > b Then
        sTxt = Mid$(sTxt, v + 1)
        sTxt = Split(sTxt)(0)
        ExtractWithoutRegex = Val(sTxt)
    End If

End Function
```