# Extract Character from Filename with RegEx in Excel VBA

Tags: regex, excel, vba, extract, filenames

My strings are filenames like this:

- Filename 1 (A12 V1.1)
- Filename 1 (V2) Text (A9 V2.3 8.99)
- Filename V2 Text (A34 8.3 V4)

How do I extract only the numbers which start with the 'V', contained within the last brackets only, and excluding the 'V'?

i.e. - 1.1, 2.3, 4

The following Regex UDF was provided by YasserKhalil ([Previous Post Here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56099989/extract-last-bracketed-characters-from-string-in-excel-vba/56100247?noredirect=1#comment98850580_56100247)

However, the UDF is returning on filenames like:

- IPV32_20.dll which returns V32-20
- IMV1.dll which returns V1.

These filenames do not contain brackets, so they should not be returning anything.

How to modify this UDF?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDII**
   Based on a comment, it seems the OP wants to return only digits and dots after the V, so we change the regex to provide that below.

The following seems to return what you describe:

```
Option Explicit
Function vNum(s As String) As String
    Dim re As Object
Set re = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With re
    .Pattern = "\(.*V([\d.]+)(?=.*\))"    
' Regex above changed from original to return only digits and dots that immediately follow the V "\(.*V(\S+)(?=.*\))"
    If .test(s) = True Then
        vNum = .Execute(s)(0).submatches(0)
    End If
End With

End Function
```

[image]

And here is a description of the regex in detail:

*Note that since your description specified "string" and not numbers, that is what this might return.  If you need to restrict it to digits and decimal, that is a simple change*

### *extract the string starting with but excluding the 'V', contained within the last brackets*

```
\(.*V(\S+)(?=.*\))
```

Options: Case sensitive; ^$ don’t match at line breaks

- [Match the opening parenthesis character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDwWz.png) `\(`
- [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*`

  - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
- [Match the character “V” literally (case sensitive)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) `V`
- [Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) `(\S+)`

  - [Match a single character that is NOT a “whitespace character” (ASCII space, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) `\S+`

    - [Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `+`
- [Assert that the regex below can be matched starting at this position (positive lookahead)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?=.*\))`

  - [Match any single character that is NOT a line break character (line feed)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) `.*`

    - [Between zero and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) `*`
  - [Match the closing parenthesis character](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TDwWz.png) `\)`

Created with [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/)

Comment: That is an excellent explanation Ron. That is a good point on string vs. number. I think a number would be preferable (if you can show me how to change that). Also, in my list, on filename "Financial Documents (Vetted).pdf", the UDF is returning "etted". It should only return numbers within brackets, even if the string starts with a "V".

Comment: @BadDogTitan Especially with Regex, (but also with other computer related specifications) it is important to be as precise as you can.  But to have the regex return only, for example, `digits` and `dots`, you would merely replace `\S` with `[\d.]`  If you wanted to limit the return to digit strings with only single dot, that could be done also.  See Edit

Comment: Point taken, Ron. Your edit works perfectly. Thanks!

Comment: Could you explain `(0).submatches(0)` please? Is it first match and first capture?

Comment: @lalebarde Yes.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that we might want to capture digits after V:

```
(?:.+V)([0-9.]+)(?:.+|$)
```

We are adding a left and right boundary here using two non-capturing groups `(?:.+V)` and `(?:.+|$)` and in the middle, `([0-9.]+)`, we are capturing our desired number.

#### [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/SCjV8d/1/)

Comment: That is going to take me a bit to absorb, Emma! But specifically, I only require the 'V' number in the filename without the 'V' (as per previous post). The extension will be variable, but I do not require it. The filenames I provided should not return anything.